# Mulitple values in PHP Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Using prepared statements, I've got 23 values that are going to be entered (see below). Does this mean I need to type out 23 ? placements or is there some kind of default / shorthand?

```
INSERT INTO table 
            (
            job_id, property_title, property_location, property_price, number_of_bedrooms, 
            number_of_receptions, number_of_bathrooms, epc, train_station_miles, 
            garden_acres, garage, off_road_parking, main_photo, 
            photo_1, photo_2, return_email, office, 
            additional_information, timestamp_added, added_by_user_id, timestamp_updated, 
            updated_by_user_id, status_id
            ) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,......etc x 23)
```

I've never thought about this before as I've only used a smaller number of values but 23 seems a bit excessive if there is some kind of shorthand

Comment: Of course you need to bind 23 parameters if that is the number of parameters you have

Comment: You have to bind 23 parameters if you have 23 parameters.

Comment: You can use named parameter if it is confusing. check documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @JigarShah Except OP is using `mysqli_` as stated in the tags

Comment: For example the user comments in the manual for mysqli_stmt::bind_param have hints on how to bind a dynamic number of values.

Comment: Appreciate the point to the comments @CBroe, had a look before coming here but missed that one - found it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be suitable for you, to shorthand binding all of your inputs into the query I'd recommend this code:

```
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, 23, '?'));

$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table 
            (
           ... rest of the statement....
            ) 
            VALUES ($placeholders)");
```

Comment: @Dan no problem, remember to keep in mind to never put in variables that contain user input into the `prepare` statement, only hard coded variables like making `$placeholders` to shorthand long SQL statements are one of the exceptions.